# X-FORWARDED-FOR header in weblogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, weblogic9.x

So I have modified the config.xml file line from

**c-ip date time time-taken cs-method cs-uri sc-status bytes**

to

**cs(X-Forwarded-For) c-ip date time time-taken cs-method cs-uri sc-status bytes**

to log the X-Forwaded-For in the access.log

However, I want to introduce an if condition that in case if the X-Forwarded-For doesn't have any information populated we populate the ip that is accessing the webserver.

If the above is not possible, After putting the above line the X-Forwarded-For Ip becomes between quotes for example like that "192.168.1.1" is it possible to have that without the quotes?

I have modified the config.xml file line from

**c-ip date time time-taken cs-method cs-uri sc-status bytes**

to

**cs(X-Forwarded-For) c-ip date time time-taken cs-method cs-uri sc-status bytes**

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained in this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/CNFGD/web_server.htm#CNFGD207). You can create your own custom fields and make them display whatever you need. Creating custom fields is explained in this [chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/CNFGD/web_server.htm#i1059518).